# Access static member of nested class when nested class shares a name with a static member of the enclosing class?

Tags: java

Is there any way to access a static member of a nested class from the enclosing class when the nested class shares a name with a static member of the enclosing class?  For example:

```
package a;

class a {
    static Object b;

    static class b {

        static Object foo;
    }

    static Object needAccessToFoo;

    static {
        // can I access foo?
    }

}
```

The class `b` (as opposed to the member `b`) can be accessed when being used as a Type via `a` (or `[b.]b.a`).  And `foo` can be accessed using the instance of the nested class `b` as so:

```
static {
    [a.][a.]b bar = new b();
    needAccessToFoo = bar.foo;
}
```

However, since `b` is a *nested class* and not an *inner class*, it leaves one to wonder if there is a proper way to statically reference `foo` without going through an instance of `b` (the object referred to by `bar`). Not to mention it's generally accepted as bad practice to access a static member via an object.

Comment: I get "java: class a is already defined in package a package"  Why would you use a lower case name for a class anyway?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I changed the example so it compiles.

Comment: Can you change it so it conforms to Java Coding Conventions with `B` for the class and `b` for the field? ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey well that would defeat the entire point of the question, wouldn't it (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is known as Obscuring. [The JLS states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2)

> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be
>   interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these
>   situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that a variable will be chosen
>   in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference
>   to a package. Thus, **it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a
>   visible type or package declaration via its simple name.** We say that
>   such a declaration is obscured.

It won't be possible to access `foo`.

In the context of the `static` initializer block there are two things with the name `b`. And because of the rule above, the variable will always be chosen when using that conflicting name. Qualifying the variable with its enclosing type, `a.b` doesn't change anything because the variable is `static` and therefore accessible through that reference.

Comment: The bolded text does say *simple* name.  However, are you suggesting I take that to mean no *fully-qualified* name either?  In that case, the implication would be there there are some cases in which you cannot access a reference, which seems unlikely (hence my question).

Comment: @David Yes, there are some cases were you would not be able to access the reference. This is one of those cases. Note, that you can access `foo` inside `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes since everything is static and `a` is in scope of your `static` block you can do:

`static {
        Object foo2 = a.foo;
        // can I access foo?
    }`

You will need to rename your outer class though to prevent a name collision.  Otherwise how will the compiler know which `a` you are referring to?

Comment: Yeah sorry I just finished editing it so it compiles.